# Thread catching reference or copy of a shared pointer, got a bizarre problem here?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, thread-safety, shared-ptr

Just see the demo I write below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

class SomethingWithVec
{
public:
    SomethingWithVec() {}
    void push(int num)
    {
        lock_guard lock(mutex_);
        v_.push_back(num);
    }
    int size()
    {
        lock_guard lock(mutex_);
        return v_.size();
    }

private:
    vector<int> v_;
    mutex mutex_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<thread> threads;
    vector<shared_ptr<SomethingWithVec>> vecs;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        auto sth = make_shared<SomethingWithVec>();
        threads.emplace_back([&sth]()
                             {
                                 while (true)
                                 {
                                     this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);
                                     printf("size at thread[%d] is %d\n", gettid(), sth->size());
                                 }
                             });
        vecs.push_back(sth);
    }
    vecs[1]->push(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        threads[i].join();
    return 0;
}
```

I create a class `SomethingWithVec` supporting concurrently r/w using mutex. And in the main function, I create 4 threads catching the reference of a corresponding shared pointer of `SomethingWithVec`. And then I modify one of the `SomethingWithVec`s outside. I expect to see that one of the threads print "size = 1", but got the following output:

```
size at thread[30819] is 0
size at thread[30822] is 0
size at thread[30821] is 0
size at thread[30820] is 0
```

It seems nothing happened after pushing a value to `vecs[1]`.

I struggled with this for quite a while, but once I change the `[&sth]` to `[sth]`, the output seems perfectly right:

```
size at thread[31595] is 0
size at thread[31597] is 0
size at thread[31598] is 0
size at thread[31596] is 1
```

Just can't figure out why? This is really weird, am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: `sth` object you capture by reference dies by the end of loop iteration. The pointed-to object is still alive, because of the other shared_ptr in vector, but your handle (pointer) is dead.

Comment: One solution is to pass `sth` by copy (this is not a problem since it is a shared pointer). Another it to reserve `vecs` to the number of threads (you can do that for `threads` too) and just provide (by copy) the pointer/reference to the inserted item. The second one is better/faster (because the `shared_ptr` is not copied which introduce a small but visible overhead). Note that you do not need a `shared_ptr` in this case: `unique_ptr` can do the job since the threads are joined by the master thread.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen 
So the thread func holds the reference of a **dead** shared pointer, but why does it still print out "size=0", should it just crash?

Comment: @AllanWang Undefined Behaviour is undefined. Anything counts as valid result. It can crash, it can print anything it wants, it can make [demons fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). What (likely) happens is that compiler allocates memory for `sth` in the same spot in stack for all loop iterations, so all four threads have reference to the same pointer (last one). Now, by sheer (mis)fortune, this place is not overwritten with anything else, so it doesn't crash when you try to read `size()`, but rather provides a result.

Comment: If you did `vecs[1]->push(1);`, all four threads could potentially show 1 as the result ([example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4TEE3eWTK)). But still, it's UB, so my guess is as good as any other guess, don't rely on that.